# Can I loop part of a collection based on index?

Tags: vba, loops

I have an unknown number of items in my collection.

I am working with one of the items in a for each loop.

Is it possible to:

- Determine the index of that item in the collection?
- Have a different loop that loops from that index to the last item of the collection?

Comment: it sounds like you need a `for` loop not `for each`

Comment: Can you show you codes for better illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection always start at 1 and you can get the number of items with the `Count` property

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    c.Add "test1"
    c.Add "test2"
    c.Add "test3"

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Debug.Print c(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```